# Get last post in each category

Tags: php, mysql

I've got 4 tables:

```
 1. forums (id,forum_id,name,group_id) - there are categories and
        sub-categories
 2. topics (id,forum_id,user_id,name,dt,deleted[default - 0])
 3. posts (id,topic_id,text,edit_dt,user_id,deleted)
 4. users (id,name)
```

---

What is the best way to get main categories last posts? Or maybe add in forums table new fields - `last_post_id`,`last_post_name`,`last_post_dt`, and at `delete,`add new topic/reply update these fields?

Comment: Your columns don't include any category columns.  Please edit your question and include sample data and desired results.

Comment: you can add a timestamp column in forum table

Comment: orderby id DESC seems simple enough unless I am missing something

Comment: @dwhite.me assuming you mean order by posts.id DESC, that would give him the posts, ordered by highest id (causes problems with import/backups) and not as asked for, the newest per category.

Comment: @newlite did you solve your problem? if so, consider writing an answer yourself so this question can be of information for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

At first, to identify your "*last post*" you should add a timestamp (DateTime) to your posts table.

Also, in your question, define what are categories (i presume it's the topics) and an example of your data, paired with an example of your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I was added fields (last_post_id,last_poster_id,last_dt) to the `forums` table, and when are inserted new/deleted/updated posts main forum will updated with newest information.

Answer (score 0):

If the database is not really huge, and you have index in all your foreign keys and ids, you could do it dinamically without creating any new fields.

I assume that the id field in the posts table is an autoincrment.
This mysql query selects the name of the last topic with some activity in each forum.

```
SELECT T.name FROM forums F 
JOIN topics T ON T.forum_id = F.id
JOIN posts P ON P.topic_id = T.id
GROUP BY F.id
ORDER BY P.id ASC
```